# Is there an `assert.deepEqual` that uses _non-strict_ equality for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, assert

I have reason to test eg. `[ { valueOf: ()=>0 } ]` to `[ 0 ]` and want that test to succeed.

Node `assert`, and Chai's various interfaces, all seem to automatically use strict equality when doing deep equality tests.

Is there an `assert.deepEqual` that will not do an `assert.deepStrictEqual` somewhere? A deep analog of `assert.equal` instead of `assert.strictEqual` ?

Answer (score 2):

All right, developing insight: it can't be done generally.

`deepEqual` will compare "all own and inherited enumerable object properties", and it will ( I am assuming here ) recursively descend on object properties until it encounters primitive values.

It has no reason to stop after the first level ( the array ), when encountering the second level ( the object ). The fact that my data actually has the encoding at the `Object` level is specific to my use case, and can not be assumed for the general case.

When arriving at primitive values for properties, *then* equality can generally usefully be non-strict.

The fact that an `Object` has a `valueOf` property ( which may or may not even be enumerable ) does not mean it should be treated as a primitive instead of an `Object`. Lots of things have a `valueOf` property.

The difference between `deepEqual` and `equal` is that `equal` *knows* it should be comparing two primitives ( or references ), and `deepEqual` can *never* know.

I was assuming too much, and asking the wrong question. Sorry SO.